# Javascript for/forEach through radio buttons

Tags: javascript

I have a question on how to for loop and forEach loop work. I have 3 code samples, 2 of them work but returning in forEach loop does not work, why ?

1. Works

   ```
   const radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("option");

   for (let i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
       if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
           return radioButtons[i];
       }
   }
   ```
2. Works

   ```
   const radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("option");
   let selectedRadioButton;

   radioButtons.forEach(function(button) {
       if (button.checked) {
           selectedRadioButton = button;
       }
   });
   return selectedRadioButton;
   ```
3. Does not work - returning in forEach

   ```
   const radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("option");

   radioButtons.forEach(function(button) {
       if (button.checked) {
           return button;
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) before posting here. `forEach` doesn't return anything. And even if it you used `map`, your third code sample doesn't do anything with the return value.

Comment: @hon2a thanks for linking to docs, I added them to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not support break behavior.
The purpose of the function is to visit each element in the array, unconditionally. The method you want is [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or in newer browsers, [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
const radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("option");

const button = radioButtons.filter(function(button) {
    return button.checked;
})[0];
```

In modern browsers:

```
const radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("option");

const button = radioButtons.find(button => button.checked);
```

It is worth noting, as D. Simon points out in his/her answer, that the `return` statement inside of a callback causes the callback itself to return, not the iteration method. JavaScript does not support what is known as non-local-return.

Here are some live examples:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  var three = values.filter(function(value) {
    return value === 3;
  })[0];

  console.info(three);
}());
```

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  const three = values.find(value => value === 3);

  console.info(three);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement in the third example returns the value to your anonymus function inside the forEach statement.